# Programmatically retrieving ECID of iphone

Tags: ios

Is there a way to find the ECID of a iPhone programmatically?

I know that this is the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978725/calling-amdevicecopyvalue-from-mobiledeviceframework-help-please/30481898#30481898 but the answers there use IOKit which has been depreciated. so is there any other way to it.

Can this be done in iOS7?

Comment: Have you written any code to try and solve this yourself? What technologies are you using?

Comment: I am working on objective c ... I want an unique id for iPhone .. As of now i am using UUID but it changes when i do factory reset or uninstall and install the app. So am looking for something which doesn't change . Thus am seeing for retriving either ECID or UDID or serial number , Please let me know it its possible in ios7

Comment: Can you explain how it isn't a duplicate? Sure seems like one to me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling AMDeviceCopyValue from MobileDeviceFramework. Help please?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978725/calling-amdevicecopyvalue-from-mobiledeviceframework-help-please)

Comment: Am also facing the same issue but i didn't find a solution to it , i commented there but couldn't get proper answer ans so i have asked it again here .

Answer (score 2):

Could you give us an idea what you need the ECID for?

Apple no longer allow of the usage of unique device ID's, the best you can get is the Vendor ID [see the docs here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor)  (Assuming you are going to be submitting to the app store). Also this ID value may change on app reinstall, which may or may not be a problem for you.

The exception to this is the Advertising ID but they may only be used for serving advertisements, [see here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AdSupport/Reference/ASIdentifierManager_Ref/).

You could also use NSUUID to generate you own ID string, [see docs here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUUID_Class/index.html)

Also, saving whatever ID value you use in the keychain will allow persistance through app reinstalls. Keychain docs are [here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/)

Comment: Ya am trying to get a uniq id only ... I have been using UUID only but it is not persistent on all occasions and thus am looking for something else such as UDID or ECID or Serial number ... is there no way to retrieve any of these .

Comment: Then likely your best solution is to use NSUUID to generate your own ID then store this within the keychain so the value persists app re-installs.

Comment: Does it remain persistent even on doing factory reset ?? ya not planning on submitting to app store

Comment: Thanks ya it works for uninstallation and re-installation but when i do factory reset and install the app again the UUID changes ... IS there any possible solution to this ??

Comment: Yes a device factory reset will clear the keychain (Erase all content and settings option, the Reset All Settings option doesn't).

Comment: ya that is why i was looking for retrieving ECID ... is there a possibility to it in iOS7 .. Till iOS5 i was able to do it but for iOS 6 and 7 it has been depreciated.. Is there any work around for this ?? N thanks for ur time..

Comment: Essentially there is no way to get a UDID that doesn't change through resets (even the advertising ID resets).
I can't really foresee a possible usage case why you would need this.

Comment: well I need to keep track of various iOS device and also who is using it . But there are scenarios where ppl have to reset the devices and thus i lose track of the device and thus i need some way to keep track of the devices under any circumstance .. Is there anything which can help me do it

Comment: The ECID is required to save SHSH2 blobs